# Scripted login into a Windows machine

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-ec2, active-directory

I am trying to spin up a bunch of windows VMs via script in Amazon EC2. Each machine has to log in with a different username. The machines are on a domain so the user accounts exist already, but I am wondering if there is any way to script the login process?

One solution I came up with is to autologin with a "bootstrap" user that automatically logs in as part of the AMI. Then I can run a script to update the autologin registry entry to whatever I want based on userdata, and then reboot the machine. However, this requires a machine reboot. Any suggestions on how to get this done without a machine restart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to logon remote session with *Remote Connection* (mstsc) and add credentials temporary with [`cmdkey`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243.aspx).

```php
# add credential
cmdkey.exe /generic:TERMSRV/$hostname /user:$username /pass:$pass

# connect remote via *mstsc*
$proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$proc.StartInfo.FileName = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe")
$proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/v:$hostname /admin"
$proc.Start()

# *wait* for the connection and then kill the remote connection
sleep -Seconds 30
$proc.Kill()

# delete stored credentials
cmdkey.exe /delete:TERMSRV/$hostname
```